# Finding at least one value of one dataframe in string values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please help me with my task please.
I have a two DataFrames in Python. One of them (df1) has a column with text strings. The second one (df2) has another text values.

df1:

| some text |
| --- |
| hello |
| world |
| my name is |
| nick |

df2:

| text to find |
| --- |
| d |
| z |
| x |
| h |

I need to check if at least the one value of df2['text to find'] is in df1['some text'] and set some flag next to each value of df1.
Finally I need to get something like this:

| some text | flag |
| --- | --- |
| hello | 1 |
| world | 1 |
| my name is | 0 |
| nick | 0 |

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with joined values by `|` for regex `or`, last cast boolean to `1,0` by converting to integers:

```
df1['flag'] = df1['some text'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['text to find'])).astype(int)
print (df1)
    some text  flag
0       hello     1
1       world     1
2  my name is     0
3        nick     0
```

If necessary test by words boundaries:

```
print (df1)
     some text
0        hello
1        world
2   my name is #<- match my
3  nick myamar #<- dont match my if substring

print (df2)
  text to find
0           my
1            z
2            x
3            h

df1['flag'] = df1['some text'].str.contains('|'.join(df2['text to find'])).astype(int)

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df2['text to find'])

df1['flag1'] = df1['some text'].str.contains(pat).astype(int)

print (df1)
     some text  flag  flag1
0        hello     1      0
1        world     0      0
2   my name is     1      1
3  nick myamar     1      0
```